# Batch command Split string and find unique

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have around 600 files of different stores in a folder. Their name is like
StoreNum_MMDD.txt/Txt/tXt/TxT/TXT. I want to find all unique StoreNum.

Please note the extension, the command should search for all possible combinations.

For eg.
If 4 files like

```
 123_0221.txt 
 32145_1220.txt 
 123_1020.TXT 
 455_0412.txT
```

then my output should be

```
123  
32145  
455
```

This is my code:

```
 FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=_ " %%i in (%FILE%) do ( echo %%i )
```

But this is generating all

```
123
32145
123
455
```

where the "123" is repeated

Comment: You've done a great job of defining your requirements. What have you done so far to try to actually implement them? We're not a code writing service, where you post what you need and someone here churns out code to meet that need. If that's what you're looking for, hire a contractor to write your code for you. We're more than willing to *help*, but we're not doing everything for you.

Comment: Hi Ken,  I have tried this                                                                          FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=_ " %%i in (%FILE%) do (
    echo %%i
)                                                                                                                            But this is generating all                                                                      123
32145                                                                                                    123
455

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Process all files and create *unique* array elements per store
for /F "delims=_" %%i in ('dir /B *.txt') do set "store[%%i]=1"

rem Show *subscripts* of elements in "store" array (not the value, that is always 1)
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%i in ('set store[') do echo %%i
```

For further details on array management in Batch files, see: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

If you have doubts about the `for` command, review the suggested link.

If you want to create an output file, enclose *the whole* last `for` command in parentheses and use a `(redirection to an) > output` file.

Comment: Personally, had the cowboys not got in first, I'd have used `if not defined store[%%i} set store[%%i]=1&echo %%i` in place of your first `set` line, making the second `for` redundant.